# Jquery Datetimepicker disable dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jquery datetime picker for getting date and time using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pickup_date').datetimepicker({
        controlType: 'select',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'           
});
```

but i need to enable 3 weeks from the current date only.How to solve this.thanks in advance

Comment: which is the plugin used

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function DisableWeekDays(date) {

 var weekenddate = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);

// In order to disable weekdays, we will invert the value returned by noWeekends functions.
// noWeekends return an array with the first element being true/false.. So we will invert the first element

 var disableweek = [!weekenddate[0]]; 
 return disableweek;
}

 $(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datetimepicker({
 beforeShowDay: DisableWeekDays
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: it works with disable of all days exept saturday and sunday only.But my need is enable dates 3 weeks from the current date only

Answer (score 0):

```
$('yourSelectorForDateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
  formatDate:'Y/m/d',
  minDate:0, //Today You can also '+1970/01/21' or '-1970/01/21' both ended up meaning -0 or +0
  maxDate:'+1970/01/21' //3*7 days from today.
});
```

use `minDate` and `maxDate`

`0` means `1970/01/01` which is start time of Unix time.You can plus/minus the String Date to set range of selectable dates.

The case You want to set the range to be yesterday to tomorrow it'll be

```
$('yourSelectorForDateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
  formatDate:'Y/m/d',
  minDate:'-1970/01/02', //Yesterday(plus one day from the 0 '1970/01/01')
  maxDate:'+1970/01/02' //Tomorrow(minus one day from the 0 '1970/01/01')
});
```

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is a good one, but if you want to set the date dynamically (based on the current date).

```
    $(function () {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var date = currentDate.toDateString();

        $("#datetimepicker1").val(new Date() + " 00:01:00");
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            minDate: date
        });
    });
```

1. Get the current date into a variable
2. Convert the date to a string
3. Pass the string to minDate

Or

```
        $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker1").val(new Date() + " 00:01:00");
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            minDate: moment()
        });
    });
```

Using JSMoment and pass moment.